# Popen acting weird when using Tshark with capture filter in Python

Tags: python, stdout, wireshark, popen, tshark

I'm having trouble passing Tshark as a command to Popen. In particular, when I add the capture filter, the program gets stuck.

```
command = ‘sudo tshark -i wlan1 -f “subtype probe-req” -n -N mnNtdv -Tfields -e wlan.ta -e wlan.ra -e wlan.seq -e wlan_radio.signal_dbm -e wlan.fc.type_subtype’
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
for packet in iter(p.stdout.readline, b’‘):
    packet_string   = packet.rstrip().decode(“utf-8") #bytes to string
    packet_info     = re.split(' |\t’, packet_string) #extract info probe request
    print(“PCKT String: “,packet_info)
```

When I remove the `-f` filter everything works fine, but when I add it the program seems stuck before the `for` loop.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just waiting for traffic but not printing anything? (Buffering could be a problem too. Does it help if you add `bufsize=1`?)

Comment: Yes, I've tried to write the output in a file, and it works. And no, I've already tried the bufsize

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it adding -l in the command